# FocusChange in ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm new to this forum and before I ask my question I searched it but didn't find an answer.

In my app I have a ListView containing 3 TextView, one is filled by a Adapter and the other 2 are for being filled by the user. If the user is now writing sowmething in the first textView and it's losing the focus I want a calculated result written into the other TextView.

My Code looks like this:

```
private final class mySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Cursor localCursor;
    private Context localContext;

    public mySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);            
        this.localCursor = c;
        this.localContext = context;

    }

    public View newView(int position, View  convertView, ViewGroup  parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)localContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_note_schueler, null); 

        String name=localCursor.getString(1);

            TextView txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblSchuelernameNoteView);
            TextView txtPunkte = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtErreichtePunkteNoteView);

            txtName.setText(name);
            txtPunkte.setOnFocusChangeListener(
                    new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            TextView txtNote = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteNoteView);
                            txtNote.setText("Test!");
                            Log.e("Check","In OnFocusChanger");
                        }
                    }
                    );
        return row;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying I found out I need to override the GetView-method